# Query issue using RavenDb with Serilog

Tags: linq, ravendb, serilog

I'm storing Serilog logevents into ravenDb.

And now I trying to write a query where all documents with a specific "dynamic" propery should be returned.

Here is my query (don't work)

```
var logsWithRole = DataSession.Query<Serilog.Sinks.RavenDB.Data.LogEvent>()
          .Where(o => o.Properties.ContainsKey("Role")).ToList();
```

And this is an example of one of the documents in ravenDb I'm trying to query:

```
{
  "Timestamp": "2014-11-20T01:20:05.5095877+01:00",
  "MessageTemplate": "{Role}, {User} logged in",
  "Level": "Information",
  "Exception": null,
  "RenderedMessage": "True, \"Steve\" logged in",
  "Properties": {
    //this propery below (Role and it's value) I'm trying to get
    "Role": true,
    "User": "Steve"
  }
}
```

Just getting a NotSupportedException: Could not understand expression: .Where(o => o.Properties.ContainsKey("Role"))

What I'm I doing wrong here? Because of Serilogs structured logging features and the nuGet integrating it with RavenDb, some query like this must be able to be done on the Properties-object and it's objects and values inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
          .Where(o => o.Properties["Role"] != null).ToList();
```